# C++ string variable in TEXT macro

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a GUI for a project, and I need to know how to use the TEXT macro with a variable.

This is what I use for printing to a UI:

```
SendMessage(console, EM_SETSEL, -1, 0);
SendMessage(console, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT(message));
```

"message" Is a string variable. I've tried it with chars too, but that still errors.

The error I get: Lmessage is undefined

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is `message`? What type is it?  Are you targeting Unicode?  I suspect that `message` is `std::string`, but should be `std::wstring`.  At that point you would write `(LPARAM)message.c_str()`. Once you've cracked that issue you might learn how to use a C++ style cast rather than a C style cast.

Comment: Personally, I'd just ditch macros like TEXT: There is really no reason to make windows applications non unicode anymore as the Windows OS has been Unicode native since Windows XP replaced the 9X family. Just use WCHAR arrays in C code, std::wstring in C++, and prefix your literals with L.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: The *entire* range of Windows NT based systems has been Unicode (UCS-2, and later UTF-16) internally throughout, starting with Windows NT 3.1, released in 1993.

Comment: @IInspectable: Releases of Window NT prior to Windows XP were released alongside the consumer oriented Windows 9X which implemented the ANSI API.  So XP represents the first version of "Windows" you can target that is only Unicode native.

Comment: @ChrisBecke: That's still somewhat misleading. Microsoft shipped the *Microsoft Layer for Unicode*, targeting Windows 95/98/ME, that introduced the wide character versions of the Windows API to those systems. With the release of the July 2001 Platform SDK there has not been a reason to not use Unicode, regardless of the target. That's still several months before general availability of Windows XP.

Comment: MSLU wasn't terribly robust though, and many developers took the understandable decision not to go down that path. The arguments here are moot though. In 2017 there is very seldom any need to support Windows 9x.

Answer (score 4):

`TEXT` is a macro that depending on other macros (`UNICODE` more specifically) can add a leading `L` to the argument of the macro.

So e.g. `TEXT("Foo")` becomes `L"Foo"` which is a wide-character (`wchar_t`) string.

Adding that leading `L` to a variable of course doesn't make the contents of the variable wide-characters, all it does is basically renaming the variable as seen with your code where `TEXT(message)` becomes `Lmessage`.

In short, you should *only* use it for literal strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `TEXT()` macro only works with compile-time literals, not with variables.  If `message` is an ANSI string and you need to send it as a Unicode string, or vice versa, then you have to perform a conversion at runtime, using `MultiByteToWideChar()`/`WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivalent.